# Find angle in degrees of a point from another point

Tags: python, math, geometry

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x: int = x
        self.y: int = y
```

I have two points `A` and `B`, where their x, y coordinate can be any integers (+ve/ 0/ -ve).
I want to find the angle in degree of one point from another.

[For example, in this case we have points A(4,3) and B(6,5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2bao.jpg)

`A.angleFromSelf(B)` should get `45` ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYRFs.png)) and `B.angleFromSelf(A)` should get `225` ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOYn.jpg)).

What is the best way of getting the angle in degrees of one point from another point?

I am thinking something like getting the slope of straight line `AB`, and then using the formula `atan(slope) = angle`, but I don’t know whether it will work when there is a negative slope.

tried:

```py
from math import atan
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def angleFromSelf(self, other):
        slope = (self.y-other.y) / (self.x-other.x)
        angle = atan(slope)
        return angle

A = Point(4,3)
B = Point(6,5)

print(A.angleFromSelf(B))
print(B.angleFromSelf(A))
```

gets:

```
0.7853981633974483
0.7853981633974483
```

expects:

```
45
225
```

Comment: Among other issues, `atan` returns radians (which is usually what you want in computations).  To get degrees, multiple by `180 / math.pi`, which gives you 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use atan2 to get the correct result

```
from math import atan2, pi
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def angleFromSelf(self, other):
        angle = atan2(self.y-other.y, self.x-other.x)
        if angle<0:
            angle+=2*pi
        return angle

def rad_2_deg(angle):
    return angle*180/pi

A = Point(4,3)
B = Point(6,5)

print(rad_2_deg(A.angleFromSelf(B)))
print(rad_2_deg(B.angleFromSelf(A)))
```